# Upgrade Android Studio 2.1 Preview3 : Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After Upgrading Android Studio to 2.1 preview 3, I am getting error while building Volley Module. However Volley Module was building successfully in Previous Android Studio Versions.

> Gradle sync failed: Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed. Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
>
> 2016-03-18 12:48:56,455 [2693134]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed. 
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed.
>
> 2016-03-18 12:48:56,455 [2693134]   WARN - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask
>
> 2016-03-18 12:48:56,455 [2693134]   INFO - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask - Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed.

Please provide any solution if anybody is able to resolve this problem.

Thanks,

Comment: Wild guess - review gradle version. Look to upgrade gradle for resolve

Comment: @RobertRowntree I am using upgraded gradle version.

Comment: For a temporary workaround, I have commented publishing {} method. As Currently,  I do not require to export module as AAR file.

Comment: how about launching the studio without any module projects once and then import the respective projects.

Comment: @7383 I have tried that workaround as well, But no luck.

Answer (score 14):

In my case, I was using volley and in build.gradle (volley) after commenting out 
`apply from: 'bintray.gradle'` , it worked !!

Comment: Does not work for me.

Comment: This worked for me. Using AndroidStudio on Mac El capitan. Will taking the latest code for volley solve this problem? I don't want to carry changes (in volley) which is not present in it's repository.